# asp.net textbox mask using jquery not working

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to use the jquery mask to apply to an **ASP.NET** web form `textbox`. Nothing I do works... what am I missing?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.maskedinput-1.2.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#phone").mask("999-999-9999");
    });
</script>
```

This is the text box code:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="phone" CssClass="rightsection" ToolTip="Please enter a phone number."></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="phone" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" Text="Required field" ValidationGroup="formfields" />
```

Comment: I figured it out eventually. The masked input jquery source code was out of date. I downloaded the latest and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

the textbox's id changes when it gets rendered to include the parent containers id, you can get the rendered id with [ClientID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx) like this

```
$("#<%= phone.ClientID%>").mask("999-999-9999");
```

> The ClientID value is generated by concatenating the ID values of each parent naming container with the ID value of the control. In data-binding scenarios where multiple instances of a control are rendered, an incrementing value is inserted in front of the control's ID value. Each segment is separated by an underscore character (_).

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>
```